# Some of the fields from the data stored in level, using model, are not persisted

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, leveldb

I'm building a issue tracking tool in an attempt to bring a more clean workflow to manage issues on a open source project.

I've into a problem using `model` and `level`, which I described in detail on this issue - https://github.com/diasdavid/issue-tracker/issues/1 -, just because it is easier to link to the right files.

It has the steps of how to repeat, any help is welcome :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `model` enforces camelCase, any property not camelCase is not saved accordingly.